# Does Facebook has RTSP server for video playing on android like YouTube?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, rtsp

In my android app, I can play youtube video with its RTSP link in VideoView. I tried to find rtsp links for videos on Facebook ending up with no results. Does anyone know how to get the rtsp link of Facebook videos ? Or is there another way to play Facebook video in my android app?

Comment: There are no rtsp links. There are http links to mp4 files